# How to install apai-io (Amazon Product API library) on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, wamp, apai-io

I tried to run apai-io [1] on a WAMP system (thanks to the XAMPP). The browser showed the message.

> You must set up the project dependencies, 
>   run the following commands:
>   (some command line code)

For me the installation seems to be written for Linux/Unix systems only. How to install apai-io on Windows to get the library working?

[1] https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io

Comment: If you have installed Composer, it should not matter if you are getting this on Unix or Windows as long as you use the Composer installation mechanism

Comment: Might also be useful to see the **(some command line code)**

Comment: The command line code is: `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php php composer.phar install`

Comment: 'curl' is not a valid command on my Windows machine :-/

Comment: How to [install composer on windows](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows)